# Watch window not working for F#

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#

I had noticed some time ago that the "Watch" window in VS2012 for Web doesn't work for default functions in FSharp. For example, `cos someValue` doesn't work, neither does the workaround where `let _cos = cos` or `let _cos x = cos x` is inserted in the beginning of the function and `_cos(someValue)` is used. The error is something like "cos doesn't exist in the current context" or "_cos isn't valid in the current scope", among others.

Should I change some settings or is this an unexpected bug? Of course I can declare all the results I need to watch, but that's a bit of overhead and it is quite impractical. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322027/how-do-i-invoke-an-f-function-from-the-vs2010-immediate-window) any help?

Comment: Often typing C# expressions instead of F# expressions in the watch window will work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the [referneced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322027/how-do-i-invoke-an-f-function-from-the-vs2010-immediate-window), the watches and immediate windows only support C#, so they are not able to evaluate F# expressions and they are not aware of the F# context (such as opened namespaces).

**In summary** storing the result in a local variable (which is compiled to an ordinary local variable) is the best way to see the result.

**More details:**
In some cases, you can write C# code that corresponds to what you want to do in F#. This is probably only worth for simple situations, when the corresponding C# is not too hard to write, but it can often be done.
For example to call `cos 3.14`, you need to write something like:

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.Cos(3.14)
```

If you find the `cos` function in the F# source code (it [righ here, in prim-types.fsi](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L2383)), then you can see that it comes with `CompiledName` attribute that tells the compiler to compile it as a method named `Cos` (to follow .NET naming guidelines). It is defined in module named `Operators` (see [it here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L1812)), which is annotated with `AutoOpen` so you do not need to explicitly write `open` in the F# code, but it is actually the name of the class that the F# compiler generates when compiling the code.

Comment: Ah, I see; although I think it doesn't make a lot of sense to write C# code to debug an F# application. That also explains why crazy class names that appear in disasseembly-like tools apear for local functions. Thank you sir for the answer.Anyway, are there any plans to allow F# code to be written on the "immediate" or "watch" windows?

Comment: I'm not sure what the current plans for this are, but you can certainly suggest & vote for the feature on: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30935-languages-f-