# F# in the Immediate Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, f#, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any such manner in which I get can either:

- F# in the immediate window in Visual Studio,
- Something functionally equivalent to the immediate window with F#

while working with a C# project?

To clarify, the immediate window behaves as expected. What I'm looking for is to be able to use something like fsi with the same context as the immediate window (paused in the debugger, able to work with / call local/private functionality). Third party solutions and hackery are welcome if they work.

Comment: What happens when you press CTRL+ALT+I ? Immediate Window does not appear at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I invoke an F# function from the VS2010 immediate window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322027/how-do-i-invoke-an-f-function-from-the-vs2010-immediate-window)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried F# Interactive? It's already more powerful than having a simple immediate window. The F# Interactive window is truly a REPL (Read-Eval-Print-Loop) feature of F# in Visual Studio.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx

Comment: FSI doesn't really help when you're paused in the debugger and want to call a function, but you're restricted to C# syntax only, and without lambda expressions to boot.

Comment: The asker is also asking about immediate window's functionality equivalent. This why I propose to use F# Interactive as REPL. FYI, F# scripts can be debugged in Visual Studio 2015. Also you can interact with F# functions easily using VS debugger in VS 2015. See https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono I apologize, my original question was not very clear and someone had removed the C# tag - I am specifically seeking the functionality of fsi in the context of the immediate window. fsi is definitely a great suggestion though.

Comment: @jdphenix if you find that my answer is useful and great, please mark it as answer :)